# iOS: openURL to UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString Preferences.app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I'm trying to get permissions from user to access camera roll here is my code:

```
PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
if (status != PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    NSString *accessDescription = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                   objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription"];
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:accessDescription
                                                                              message:@"To give permissions tap on 'Change Settings' button"
                                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                         handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    UIAlertAction *settingsAction = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"Change Settings"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]
                                           options:@{}
                                 completionHandler:nil];

    }];
    [alertController addAction:settingsAction];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController
                                                                                 animated:YES
                                                                               completion:nil];

}
```

But when the user press "Change Settings" and it's trying to access the system preference:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]
                                               options:@{}
                                     completionHandler:nil];
```

I'm getting this crash:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             Preferences [4364]
Path:                /Applications/Preferences.app/Preferences
Identifier:          com.apple.Preferences
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.Preferences [1370]


Date/Time:           2017-05-16 15:43:24.1235 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-05-16 15:43:23.3450 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x190c12fd8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18f674538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x190c12f20 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
3   Foundation                      0x1916780b4 -[NSBundle initWithURL:] + 104
4   Foundation                      0x191678038 +[NSBundle bundleWithURL:] + 48
5   PreferencesUI                   0x1a3fd54dc -[PSUIPrefsListController _reallyLoadThirdPartySpecifiersForApps:withCompletion:] + 740
6   PreferencesUI                   0x1a3fd50d8 -[PSUIPrefsListController loadThirdPartySpecifierIfNeededForBundleID:] + 416
7   Preferences                     0x1000a0710 0x100094000 + 50960
8   Preferences                     0x10009e138 0x100094000 + 41272
9   UIKit                           0x196fcd180 __45-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:]_block_invoke + 964
10  UIKit                           0x196fccb34 -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:] + 644
11  UIKit                           0x196fbf9e8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3940
12  UIKit                           0x196fc52a8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
13  UIKit                           0x196fd9de0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3151 + 48
```

Any of you knows why or what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there some additional exception message in your console?

Comment: @Paulw11, there is no output in the console. The log I posted is from my the device.

Comment: If you open settings on your device, is there a settings entry for your app?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

The method you are using is available from iOS 10 and if you will run app below ios 10 then it will crash.

Either check for iOS version before calling method or use above method.